# Unable to get value from Json.parse getting undefined value in Angular js MVC

Tags: json, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to fetch value from json.parse getting undefined value .

here is code,

```
var result = JSON.parse(d.data.data);
var name = result["TasksId"];
```

In result variable i have value in this form:

```
"{
  "result": [
    {
      "AssignedBy": "724523c9-6d0d-4c69-9ee1-5d17b0271bbc",
      "UserId": "980392bd-96ce-4940-87e7-bb9e8f805f60",
      "Id": 5872,
      "TaskId": 1485
    }
  ]
}"
```

TaskId exist in it even than i am getting undefined

Hopes for your suggestions

Thanks

Comment: Are you getting other values correctly? Try with  result["Id"] and see if you have the value

Comment: @georg getting undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check your object, It has an array in it

```
"{
  "result": [
    {
      "AssignedBy": "724523c9-6d0d-4c69-9ee1-5d17b0271bbc",
      "UserId": "980392bd-96ce-4940-87e7-bb9e8f805f60",
      "Id": 5872,
      "TaskId": 1485
    }
  ]
}"
```

so you must give the proper path(index) to it , so try using `result['result'][0]['TaskId']`

Comment: i tried it gave me error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'TasksId' of undefined'

Comment: in your case you have it as ```result["result"][0]["TaskId"]```. Here the logic is to use index of the array which you wanna display

Comment: Glad that i'm able to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

here, result is an nested object. For accessing the outer key, you have to use either dot notation like result.result or [] notation like result["result"]. 
The value of result["result"] is an array for which values to be accessed by [index].

`result["result"][0]["TaskId"]`